# Launch Ansible Job Template Response

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am launching an Ansible Job template which creates infrastructure in my AWS cloud, Is there a way to know what all resources are provisioned from as part of this job template?

Interested in resource information :  'resourceId'.

Eg playbook :

```
    - amazon.aws.ec2:
        key_name: mykey
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: ami-123456
        wait: yes
        group: webserver
        count: 3
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
        assign_public_ip: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to register and print the output of the previous command and based on the output values you can traverse to the exact value you need.

`register: output`

And to print the output you can use debug module

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ output }}"
```

So the complete code will look like

```
- amazon.aws.ec2:
    key_name: mykey
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-123456
    wait: yes
    group: webserver
    count: 3
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
    assign_public_ip: yes
  register: output

- debug:
   msg: "{{ output.stdout }}"
```